# How to open a new div when I click on a tree node

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have this Primefaces tree:

***JSF code***

```
<h:form id="form">  

    <p:tree id="tree" value="#{TreeViewController.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="true" animate="true">  
        <p:treeNode>  
            <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>  
        </p:treeNode> 
    </p:tree>  

</h:form>
```

***Managed Bean***

```
private TreeNode root;  

    public TreeView() {  
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);  
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);  
        TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2", root);  

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);  
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);
        TreeNode node02 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.2", node0);  
        TreeNode node03 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.3", node0);
        TreeNode node04 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.4", node0);  
        TreeNode node05 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.5", node0);
        TreeNode node06 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.6", node0);
        TreeNode node07 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.7", node0);  
        TreeNode node08 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.8", node0);  

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);  
        TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1", node1);  

        TreeNode node000 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0", node00);  
        TreeNode node001 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1", node00);  
        TreeNode node010 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0", node01);  

        TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);  
    }  

    public TreeNode getRoot() {  
        return root;  
    }
```

I'm interested how I can open a new div containing additional information of the node. I want to give to the user opportunity to browse the nodes. When he clicks on a node on the right side of the tree to see additional information in additional layer. How I can do this?

I found the tag attribute `onNodeClick` which is used to call JavaScript when tree node is clicked. Maybe with JS I can open a new div?

***Not working solution***
I tested this code but it's not working:

```
<h:form id="form">  

    <p:tree id="tree" value="#{TreeViewController.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="true" animate="true">  
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeSelect}" update="outputComponent" />
        <p:treeNode>                            
            <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>  
        </p:treeNode> 
    </p:tree>

    <p:outputPanel id="outputComponent">
        <h:outputText value="#{TreeViewController.onNodeSelect}" />
    </p:outputPanel>

</h:form>  

public String onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
        String node = event.getTreeNode().getData().toString();

        return node;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if you can add ajax behavior to this `onNodeClick` method to update a `<p:panel>` or another UIContainer that's right to your `<p:tree>` in order to do what you need. If you can't, just write a hidden link (`<p:commandLink style="display:none">`) and in the `onNodeClick` js method click this link to process the data to show and update the UIContainer to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is in the docs (code below is an excerpt of it). Either you use the onNodeClick to call a custom JavaScript method to show your "div" or, and this is what I suggest, you use a ajax event.

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeSelect}" update="outputComponent" />
```

Then you can handle the event on the server side:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    String node = event.getTreeNode().getData().toString();
    // prepare data you want to show
}
```

And then have an output component in place, such as an :

```
<p:outputPanel id="outputComponent">
    <!-- reference the bean in which you put your informatnoi in the onNodeSelect listener-->
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I updated the post. Sorry but I'm new to Java. Do you see anywhere the problem why the code is not working?

Comment: 1st of all I hope you put the java method into the managed bean you named TreeViewController. 2nd the method signature of the event listener method must remain unchanged, meaning its return type remains void as in the example. 3rd you want to change a property or the like in the listener method "onNodeSelect", this property you can reference in the h:outputText-component you've added. You cannot  use the listener method for value binding of the output-component. I suggest you start with a JSF tutorial in order to get these basics, otherwise it will be hard for you to manage it.